# Segmentation fault after mmap()

Tags: c++, linux, unix, mmap

I wanna share a pointer of map during 2 processes. So I tried mmap. I tested mmap in a single process. Here is my code:

```
#include  <vector>
#include  <iostream>
#include  <sys/mman.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <cstdlib>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    map<string,string> a, *b;

    b = (map<string,string> *)mmap(&a,sizeof(map<string,string>),
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED,-1,0);

    b->insert(map<string,string>::value_type("a","b")); //error 
    cout << b->size() << endl;
}
```

when it runs to `b->insert()`, Segmentation fault occured. If I remove `b->insert()`, there is no error (still have `b->size`). What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Even if you will be able to use map allocated in mmap, it can't be shared between processes. STL doesnt store all elements inside the b, it uses pointers and classic allocators working via new/delete or malloc/free. If you really need to share some structure of data, you need to define & implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating new memory with `mmap` (why? seems like a bad idea...) but you are not initializing your `map`.  Use "placement new" to initialize it.

```
void *p = mmap(....);
if (p == MAP_FAILED)
    abort();
map<string,string> *b = new(p) map<string,string>();
b->insert(...);
```

But I suspect something is terribly wrong, and `mmap` really shouldn't be involved here...

**Edit:** From the comments, it sounds like you want to share memory between two processes.  Shared memory is probably far beyond your current skill level.  You cannot normally place a `std::map` object inside a shared memory segment, because it will contain references to internal objects on the heap, which will not be shared, unless you can create a custom allocator to only create subobjects inside the shared memory segment.

You can create a shared memory object with `shm_open`, you can change its size with `ftruncate`, and you can map it into memory with `mmap`.  Different processes that `shm_open` the same name will get the same object, and the shared object descriptor can also be passed between processes just like file descriptors.

Comment: I just want to share a map between multiple processes, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Despite its name, `mmap()` has nothing to do with `std::map`. When you use `mmap()`, you get access to a raw block of memory with no structure. You cannot directly store STL objects like `std::map` in that block, because there are internal pointers inside the STL objects that are not compatible with `mmap()`.

When you use `mmap()` to map the same block of memory into two different processes, that block may not even appear at the same address in memory. You must take this into account when defining the format of data you will store in the shared memory.